# AWS S3 Bucket Policy to block access to all but one directory, even if user has full S3 permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but I would like to create a setup similar to what is described in:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

by creating an S3 bucket with a subdirectory for each AWS user accessible only to that user.

My question is: is it possible to go a step further and specifically block users that might otherwise have full S3 permissions from being able to read from subdirectories that don't belong to them?

This solution would be ideal for me, except that several users have */* on S3 which I believe will override this policy for them, allowing them to see other users' data. Ideally this would be a bucket policy rather than an IAM group/role so that any user in the account automatically has these permissions applied without needing to be added to a group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an IAM user/role accesses an S3 bucket, all of the following policies are applied:

- The user's or role's IAM policies,
- If the user is in any groups, all of those group's policies, and
- If the bucket being accessed has a bucket policy, that policy.

All of those policies work as follows:

1. All commands are denied, unless
2. There is an explicit allow in any policy, unless
3. There is an explicit deny in any policy.

Basically, what this means is that by default, access is denied, unless you add an "Allow" statement to a policy (IAM user/role, group, or bucket). But if you explicitly add a "Deny" statement (in any affecting policy), that "Deny" statement will overrule any other "Allow" statement.

Knowing this, you can apply a bucket policy to your S3 bucket with the correct "Deny" statements. These policy statements would overrule any other policy statements, applying to anyone accessing the bucket (even the super-est of super users).

So, you can try something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "blah",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyListingOfUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::block-test",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "home/",
                        "home/${aws:username}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy will deny anyone from listing the contents from any folder aside from the root folder, "home" folder, and "home/their user name" folder.

Be careful when working with "Deny" staetments. **The wrong policy could lock you out of your own bucket and you'll need AWS support to remove the policy for you.**

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that this would deny listing of objects in the bucket, but would not in fact prevent GETting or PUTting objects from/to the bucket if a user with full permissions knew the object's key? If so how would this policy be updated to prevent getting objects as well?

Comment: You can modify the policy to include more commands in the `Action` list. So you can add `s3:GetObject` and `s3:PutObject`. Highly recommended NOT to add `s3:*`.