# How Do I Allow GetObject for Public, GetObject+PutObject+DeleteObject for EC2 Instance?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to set a policy that allows GetObject for public, and GetObject, PutObject, DeleteObject for my Django application in an EC2 Instance.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141675/aws-s3-bucket-policy-to-block-access-to-all-but-one-directory-even-if-user-has), it seems that the following bucket policy should do the job:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1683280060839",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1683280008173",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-project-bucket-2023/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1683280057104",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::667802944954:role/MyProject"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-project-bucket-2023/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

It allows GetObject for all, and in addition to that, allows DeleteObject and PutObject to IAM Role. I have assigned this role to the EC2 Instance. All public access is blocked.

But I can still put objects to my bucket from localhost where I have not provided ACCESS_KEY. I have set up storage information in settings.py, but as you can see below, ACCESS_KEY is commented out.

```py
# AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
# AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "my-project-bucket-2023"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + ".s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

I have tried a lot of other policies, and they all were not successful.

How can I allow GetObject to public, deny all others, and allow GetObject, PutObject, DeleteObject to my django project in an EC2 Instance?

Comment: Please show us the code that is "putting objects to my bucket from localhost".

Comment: It's `image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='posts/images', ...)` in a model. I guess you don't need the entire code (do you?), as I commented to your answer, it was because the credentials existed as environment variables by `load_dotenv()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an IAM Role has been assigned to the instance, then any code running on the instance that uses an AWS SDK (eg boto3) will **retrieve access credentials from the EC2 Instance Metadata Service**.

There is **no need for your code to retrieve credentials from Environment Variables**, unless you have specifically added credentials to Environment Variables and you wish to use those credentials instead of the IAM Role.

By the way, when granting permission for an IAM User or an IAM Role to use an Amazon S3 bucket, it is preferable to **put those permissions directly on the IAM User / IAM Role** rather than using a Bucket Policy. Bucket Policies are typically used for granting Public or Cross-account permissions rather than granting user-specific permission.

Comment: By localhost I meant server that is running on my laptop which is outside the EC2. Sorry for the unclarity. So it should have not been able to put object, if only GetObject were allowed, right?

Comment: In that case, you probably have some credentials stored in your `~/.aws/credentials` file. On your laptop, run the command `aws  sts get-caller-identity` to discover what credentials you are actually using.

Comment: It says `Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".`

Comment: Do you have an ACL on your Bucket that might be allowing you to write to it?

Comment: If you **remove** the Bucket Policy, can the app still write to the bucket?

Comment: ACL only allows read and write to bucket owner. If I remove the Bucket Policy, I can still write to the bucket(EC2 Instance has IAM role that has AmazonS3FullAccess). But as I remove AdministratorAccess from the user whose key I used to use for testing purpose, localhost can no longer write to the bucket, while EC2 still can. It seems that boto3(or django-storages?) is behaving like it remembers(caches) my credentials.

Comment: To see where boto3 obtains credentials (known as the "Credentials Chain"), see: [Credentials - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html)

Comment: I see. Although I did not getenv AWS credentials in python, because they already existed as environment variable, boto3 looked up and used them to reach AWS services.